# Templatize a file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I have a requirement where i have a config file which has a bunch of properties. The user has to download the property file from the server using a browser. Some of these properties have to be changed based on the user's input and then the file has to be downloaded. This basically fits the perfect description of having templates and then at run time generating a file by replacing the properties provided by the user. How can i achieve this using node js. Any pointer will be deeply appreciated. Please pardon my limited knowledge of MEAN stack.

Answer (score 0):

Template engines are a common thing and it's quite easy to use one with express.

I suggest you start with the docs on [using template engines with express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html). They also have a wiki entry with a list of [available engines](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki#template-engines).

Most template engines are meant to generate HTML, if you want to output something else (even plaintext) it can be a bit tricky sometimes.

Otherwise the choice mainly depends on what your familiar with. I can recommend [Mozilla Nunjucks](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks).